# New NVIDIA GTX 960 Strix 2 GB – No video output after Windows logo

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I have recently put together a new PC with the inclusion of a GTX 960. After doing a fresh install of Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and installing all drivers (including NVIDIA driver v.359) everything was running perfectly. I played more than 8 hours of Fallout 4 without a hiccup.

I then bought some Steam games and left my computer on when I went to work to let them download. Once I got home, it appeared as if my computer was still on, but there was no video output at all. I restarted my computer and the first thing I noticed was that in the place of the 'Starting Windows' logo was the 'Microsoft Corporation' with the loading bar that you see when doing a repair. A few seconds afterwards, the screen went black, and my video card stopped outputting anything.

I completed a fresh installation of Windows which fixed the problem for a couple of days, and then the same thing happened. I am almost certain that it is the NVIDIA drivers, because I can boot the computer with no problem in safe mode using the generic video driver, and then when I uninstall the NVIDIA driver in safe mode, the computer boots up perfectly (except for the fact that the Microsoft Corporation logo is still there).

I have rolled back to the previous drivers with no success too. I am at a loss, and I know it has nothing to do with the video card because it has been used in another computer for about a month with no issues.

The only "questionable component" in the computer is the HDD, just because it is an old Seagate drive, and I will replace that soon. However, I don't see how this could be the cause of this issue.

I would really appreciate any help I can get – I have been stuck on this for too long and it is becoming very frustrating.